# Different or identical nature of a pair terminology with respect to shoes/socks and other problems?

Tags: combinatorics

My query is regarding [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2022928/688539). I want clarification of the last step of the calculation where $2^2=4$ choices is identified for every pair of different color sock.

Do we need to always assume different in pairs too unless any problem mentions this ? If I don't consider the different to be identical I was getting exactly $\frac{1}{4}$th of the answer given there. Why should we scale up the number of pair of different color sock (=15) by four?

Comment: In the top votes one and the op method both uses the convention of different socks even in pairs :(. @Buraian

Comment: Yes right Buraian

Comment: Here is the version where socks was used : https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/there-are-8-different-pairs-of-socks-the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-a-total/ . I am just confused regarding how to decide when to consider them different if not mentioned in problem and when not

Comment: Oh you not getting my point , i said each pair colour etc  can be different from others but not in itself among themselves

Comment: Yeah there are 16 shoes are we assuming any matching pair of shoes are distinct ? That what my problem is in short as nothing is being mentioned clearly in the problem thats why i took ** same colour and same object**  in every matching pair

Comment: Oh can you explain the final step where Marc used 2^2 , by my thinking it should be 1 only hence getting 1/4th of the answer

Comment: My thinking is every matching pair is (AA) ,( BB) etc . So they are just difference in colour but in every  matching pair its same . So thats why only 1 instead of 2^2 in final step

Comment: In original post figure you can assume my thinking is that 1=2 , 3= 4 ....

Comment: I've deleted comments which are irrelevant after the most recent edit I made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually a great question I think. I thought for quite a bit and I think I figured out what's going wrong. I believe that in the linked answer, Marc is considering the orientation of shoe. In sense that he is accounting for the fact that there is a difference between the kind of shoe which goes on the left foot vs the kind which goes on the right foot.

To drill in the point, after we choose first two pair, we have only have two more shoes we can select. Let us split the total set of twelve oriented shoes into two sets of six shoes each of common orientation. The total number of selections we can choose for the twelve oriented shoe set can be counted through the split sets.

Let us call one of the split set of seven elements as $R$ and the other as $L$. We have the following possibilities of selection:

1. Choose both from $R$
2. Choose one element from $R$ and none from $L$.. but here we have to be careful, suppose we choose a certain color from $R$ .. we can't choose same from $L$. The way of choosing same color is six.
3. Choose both from $L$

We can count the total ways as:

$$ \binom{6}{2} \binom{6}{0} + \left[\binom{6}{1} \binom{6}{1}-6 \right]+ \binom{6}{0}\binom{6}{2}$$

We can simplify the above by Vandermonde identity as $\binom{12}{2}-6$ which is exactly the expression which Christian Blatter arrived at.

Comment: [Relevant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vandermonde%27s_identity)

Comment: Thanks exactly that what i was asking , but yeah so if we didnt account for orientation will you agree that answer will come out to be 1/4th of the above answer ?

Comment: Yep the whole last step Marc did is then not needed @ProblemDestroyer

Comment: I mean, I would like to add a point that it is somewhat natural to consider orientation. It's not like he thought "Oh yeah better multiply consider orientation". You can check easily that a left foot will be very uncomfortable on right foot one @ProblemDestroyer

Comment: Hmm understood @Buraian

Comment: Note that even in [the Toppr question and answer](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/there-are-8-different-pairs-of-socks-the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-a-total/), where the question says "socks", the answer says "shoes".
In fact the answer is practically word-for-word the same as the core part of
[the linked stackexchange answer](https://www.toppr.com/ask/question/there-are-8-different-pairs-of-socks-the-number-of-ways-of-selecting-a-total/), right down to the emphasis of the word "incomplete". I am not sure this is a good example to follow.

Comment: While plagirism is an issue, The orientation issue holds for the sock as well, so technically the answer is right there though they calculated diff thing :P @DavidK

Comment: Oops, I meant to comment on the question, not this answer. I completely agree with this answer and with the linked math.se answer. The point about Toppr was that if they're too lazy to write a proper answer then they might also not bother to write a proper question.